# Moving focus from JTextArea using tab key

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

As stated, I want to change the default TAB behaviour within a `JTextArea` (so that it acts like a `JTextField` or similar component)

Here's the event action

```
private void diagInputKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    if(evt.KEY_PRESSED == java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_TAB) {
        actionInput.transferFocus();
    }
}
```

And here's the listener

```
diagInput.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
        diagInputKeyPressed(evt);
    }
});
```

I've tried evt.KEY_TYPED as well with no joy.

Any ideas?

quick edit: I've also tried `requestFocus()` in place of `transferFocus()`

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042429/how-can-i-modify-the-behavior-of-the-tab-key-in-a-jtextarea

Answer (score 29, accepted):

According to [this class](http://www.koders.com/java/fidEFE6DD3BBD50DC8AAAE60012E847110CBE3EF7A8.aspx?s=mdef%3Ainsert):

```
/**
 * Some components treat tabulator (TAB key) in their own way.
 * Sometimes the tabulator is supposed to simply transfer the focus
 * to the next focusable component.
 * <br/>
 * Here s how to use this class to override the "component's default"
 * behavior:
 * <pre>
 * JTextArea  area  = new JTextArea(..);
 * <b>TransferFocus.patch( area );</b>
 * </pre>
 * This should do the trick. 
 * This time the KeyStrokes are used.
 * More elegant solution than TabTransfersFocus().
 * 
 * @author kaimu
 * @since 2006-05-14
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class TransferFocus {

    /**
     * Patch the behaviour of a component. 
     * TAB transfers focus to the next focusable component,
     * SHIFT+TAB transfers focus to the previous focusable component.
     * 
     * @param c The component to be patched.
     */
    public static void patch(Component c) {
        Set<KeyStroke> 
        strokes = new HashSet<KeyStroke>(Arrays.asList(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed TAB")));
        c.setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, strokes);
        strokes = new HashSet<KeyStroke>(Arrays.asList(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("shift pressed TAB")));
        c.setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.BACKWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, strokes);
    }
}
```

Note that `patch()` can be even shorter, according to [Joshua Goldberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/411282/joshua-goldberg) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525855/moving-focus-from-jtextarea-using-tab-key/525867#comment37587468_525867), since the goal is to get back default behaviors overridden by `JTextArea`:

```
component.setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERS‌​AL_KEYS, null);
component.setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.BACKWARD_TRAVERS‌​AL_KEYS, null);
```

This is used in question "[How can I modify the behavior of the tab key in a `JTextArea`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5043957/6309)"

---

The [previous implementation](http://www.koders.com/java/fid0F02F3C453624EDF1564C356CC30EFC1561774E9.aspx?s=mdef%3ainsert) involved indeed a `Listener`, and the a `transferFocus()`:

```
   /**
     * Override the behaviour so that TAB key transfers the focus
     * to the next focusable component.
     */
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_TAB) {
            System.out.println(e.getModifiers());
            if(e.getModifiers() > 0) a.transferFocusBackward();
            else a.transferFocus(); 
            e.consume();
        }
    }
```

`e.consume();` might have been what you missed to make it work in your case.

Comment: needed to change to getKeyCode() and evt.consume() - evt.consume() got rid of the tab character and using getKeyCode() allows it to successfully moved the focus using tab.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You are welcome. I wonder if the first implementation (the one modifying the FocusTraversalKeys of a Component) is not "cleaner" in a way, though...

Comment: wow, good answer, always the same exemplary attention to detail :)

Comment: `patch` can be simpler, since you want to get back default behaviors overridden by JTextArea.  Just 2 lines: `component.setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.{FORWARD,BACKWARD}_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, null)`  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5043957/411282