# How to move one field to another field using tab key using swing?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jcomponent, gridbaglayout

I am creating a class which extends `JPanel`.There are several textareas and drop downs which I have added in that panel using `GridBagConstraints`. Now I want to move one field to another using tab key of keyboard. I also want to mention that previously the tab key was expanding the textareas.

That is why I wrote this line: `restuarantLocation.setTabSize(0);` Now it stopped expanding.

But I do not know how can i make work the tab key? Please help.

Comment: Clarification: Do you want to use the TAB key to move from one component to the other?

Comment: If you want to "disable" the default behavior of the TAB key in a `JTextArea` you can have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042429/how-can-i-modify-the-behavior-of-the-tab-key-in-a-jtextarea)

Answer (score 5):

When you press TAB inside any text area - it creates the tabulation symbol. So your code `setTabSize(0)` doesn't fix anything - it just sets the tabulation width to zero.

In case you are simply looking for focus change hotkey - Ctrl+TAB will work instead simple TAB inside any Swing text component and will switch focus to next available and focusable component. Ctrl+Shift+TAB will switch focus to previous available and focusable component.

In case you want TAB to act in the same way as in the other Swing components - you might add your custom TAB action:

```
public static void main ( String[] args )
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater ( new Runnable ()
    {
        public void run ()
        {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame ();

            frame.setLayout ( new GridLayout ( 1, 2 ) );

            AbstractAction transferFocus = new AbstractAction ()
            {
                public void actionPerformed ( ActionEvent e )
                {
                    ( ( Component ) e.getSource () ).transferFocus ();
                }
            };

            JTextArea textArea1 = new JTextArea ();
            textArea1.getInputMap ().put ( KeyStroke.getKeyStroke ( "TAB" ), "transferFocus" );
            textArea1.getActionMap ().put ( "transferFocus", transferFocus );
            frame.add ( new JScrollPane ( textArea1 ) );

            JTextArea textArea2 = new JTextArea ();
            textArea2.getInputMap ().put ( KeyStroke.getKeyStroke ( "TAB" ), "transferFocus" );
            textArea2.getActionMap ().put ( "transferFocus", transferFocus );
            frame.add ( new JScrollPane ( textArea2 ) );

            frame.setSize ( 500, 200 );
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo ( null );
            frame.setVisible ( true );
        }
    } );
}
```

Notice that you have to:

1. Replace the default tab KeyStroke with your action name first in the input map
2. Add your custom action into component action map

Comment: Thanks a lott. Can i use jpanel instead of jframe?

Comment: @user1568579 it doesn't matter where you add text areas

Answer (score 0):

If the built in tabbing doesn't work, you might want to take a look at the Java tutorial on focus traversal.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html

Comment: Thank you.But i need solution.i have few idea about swing.But still thnks.I am going through the link.:)

Comment: @user1568579 _I need a solution_ We need a clearer question showing a concrete example of non-working code. Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and answers will be raining on your post.

Comment: @user1568579 and after this comment [please to read StackOverflow FQA](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 0):

use this example:

```
Vector vector=new Vector(3);
vector.Add(textBox1);
vector.Add(textBox2);
vector.Add(textBox3);
clsTabOrder newPolicy=new clsTabOrder(vector);
setFocusTraversalPolicy(newPolicy);
textBox1.requestFocus();
```

Comment: Suggest http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting might help you make better formatting.

Answer (score 0):

```
 jTextField1.setNextFocusableComponent(jTextField2);
    jTextField2.setNextFocusableComponent(jTextField3);
    jTextField3.setNextFocusableComponent(jTextField4);
    jTextField4.setNextFocusableComponent(jTextField5);
```

when you wont show the jframe click auto click jtextfild

```
 this.jTextField11.requestFocusInWindow();
```