# How can I find out which keys are pressed without a listener?

Tags: java

(tl;dr below)

I'm writing a program containing several JFormattedTextFields and JTextAreas. You can imagine it like a simple form.

Usually, when you're inside a JFormattedTextField an press *tab*, the next JFormattedTexField/JTextArea gets the focus or the previous JFormattedTexField/JTextArea gets the focus when you press *shift + tab*. This behaviour is just fine. My problem is, that this doesn't work for the JTextAreas. The first solution I had in my mind for this was a KeyListener which looks like this:

```
private class MultiKeyPressListener implements KeyListener {
    private final Set<Integer> pressed;
    private final JComponent prev;
    private final JTextArea current;
    private final JComponent next;

    public MultiKeyPressListener(Set<Integer> pressedKeys, JComponent prev, JTextArea current, JComponent next) {
        super();
        this.pressed = pressedKeys;
        this.prev = prev;
        this.current = current;
        this.next = next;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        pressed.add(e.getKeyCode());
        if (pressed.size() == 1) {
            if (pressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_TAB)) {
                next.requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        } else if (pressed.size() == 2) {
            if (pressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT) && pressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_TAB)) {
                prev.requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        pressed.remove(e.getKeyCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        current.setText(current.getText().replaceAll("\t", ""));
    }
}
```

(The variable `pressedKeys` is shared between all JTextAreas. I also tried it without sharing which doesn't really matter. In both cases there are some problems.)

Basically it seems fine, but there's a problem if you want to jump three textfields upwards for example. Let's imagine you're in a JFormattedTextField and above it is a JTextArea you want to jump to. You press *shift* and then *tab*. Now you're inside the JTextArea and you're already pressing *shift*, which results in a KeyListener not recognising the pressed *shift*-button, because it's already pressed down. Therefore, if you press *tab* now (still keeping the *shift*-button pressed from before), you jump to the textfield below instead to the textfield above because the *shift*-button isn't recognised.

My idea to solve this would be quite simple, although I can't find out, if there's even a method for it. Every time *tab* is pressed, I check, if *shift* is pressed as well. Therefore I need a function which returns all currently pressed keys. In this case, the code would look like this:

```
@Override
public synchronized void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_TAB) {
        if (Keys.getAllPressedKeys().contains(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT)) {
            prev.requestFocusInWindow();
        } else {
            next.requestFocusInWindow();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something like this? Or is there any other way to solve this? I mean... I could add this listener too all textfields I use for the form, but that would be quite unhandy.

**tl;dr**: Is there a way to change the focus by pressing *tab*/*shift+tab* when using a JTextArea so it behaves the same like a JTextField/JFormattedTextField does when programming something similar to a form?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525855/moving-focus-from-jtextarea-using-tab-key and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042429/how-can-i-modify-the-behavior-of-the-tab-key-in-a-jtextarea/5043957#5043957

Comment: Key Bindings probably would work. I try to avoid adding KeyListeners to text components as that can cause disaster.

Comment: Yep, go with camickr's Key Binding solution as per @copeg's second link.