# How to Set JComponent to Traverse with TAB instead of CTRL+TAB without using isManagingFocus()

Tags: java, swing, keyboard

I have a class that is a custom swing component that extends JComponent. I am trying to make it so that the subcomponents of this custom component will be focus traversable by simply pressing TAB or SHIFT+TAB. Instead, they only seem to be traversable by pressing CTRL+TAB or CTRL+SHIFT+TAB by default no matter what I specify otherwise. I have referred to the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525855/moving-focus-from-jtextarea-using-tab-key) although my component is not a JTextArea, and I have tried setting the focus traverse keys directly with the code below in the constructor, but to no avail.

```
setFocusCycleRoot(true);
setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(true);
Set<AWTKeyStroke> forwardKeys = new HashSet<>();
forwardKeys.add(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, 0));
setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, forwardKeys);
Set<AWTKeyStroke> backwardKeys = new HashSet<>();
backwardKeys.add(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, InputEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK));
setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.BACKWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, backwardKeys);
```

I also tried to add a key listener to the component to effectively do the same thing with the code below, but that also did not work.

```
addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_TAB) {
            if (e.isShiftDown()) {
                transferFocusBackward();
            } else {
                transferFocus();
            }
            e.consume();
        }
    }
});
```

I find that I get exactly the behavior I want if I do not include the either of the code blocks above, but rather override the isManagingFocus() method to always return true, but I would rather not do this as isManagingFocus() is deprecated.

Comment: By default, it should "just" work - consider providing a [mcve] that demonstrates your current problem

Comment: Why without "isManagingFocus"? If this is how default tabbing is designed to work, then why try to reinvent the wheel?